# Vue.js [V3] How to focus an element located in a parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I currently have the following HTML tree:

```
<!-- App.vue -->
<main>
  <!-- Header.vue -->
  <header>
     <!-- Nav.vue -->
     <nav>
        <button type="button">Click here should focus on the <a> link</button>     
     </nav>
  </header>
  <a ref="link" tabindex="0">External link</a>
</main>
```

When clicking on the `button`, I need to focus on the `<a>`. How can I get the reference to this  link in my Nav.vue file ?

I can do something like `this.$parent.$parent.refs.link.focus()` but that is not very maintainable and I would rather not.

Comment: I guess you should do an emit to the parent, and there listen to it and focus the desired element

Comment: @ericmp yes, it's more cleaner than using `$parent` indeed.

Comment: we always meet here @kissu, xD

Comment: Cool, thanks for the suggestion, I thought there would be another way, but I will emit an event indeed !

Comment: Still the most clean way of doing things in Vue, DOM manipulation is more of a last resort usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [event emitting](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html).

**Nav.vue**

```html
<template>
  <button 
    @click="$emit('handleFocus')"
    type="button"
  >
    Click here should focus on the <a> link
  </button>
</template>
```

**Parent Component**

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <Header>
      <!-- Nav.vue -->
      <Nav @handle-focus="handleFocus" />
    </Header>
    <a ref="link" tabindex="0">External link</a>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleFocus() {
      this.$refs.link.focus()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: :( i was writing an example too, but np

Comment: @ericmp could have still written it given the various errors of the initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use [emits](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html). I have set up a Vue3 Composition API example. Check it out [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqlUstuwjAQ/JWVL6QSSe4IEBXi0FvvdSVC2LQBv2RvaCuUf+/ahEep1Etv3p31eHbGR/HoXHHoUEzElFA7VRHOpZkurXawaGzdhdxVHg3lqGZS1JVSm6reSwElz/Fka1xH4LFhVH89xWoAp+UNI5eh9q0jCEid406rnfUEx3gXemi81TBiKaMLlESc+kUZi6iUYWlqawLB8BzMIkVmOqUeruBZKaPZA8zm5+niUKkOi7RaxvPT8qRrLsbi9G6uK1fsgjVsylEaADkAQYoJpE7ssZZYS/FO5MKkLENTR4G7UFj/VvKp8J2hVmOBQecbbz8CeiaWYnzDUXLzgD5nj7fo0f/FeTf6izfS9tL0vMrZrvtgNx2RZZMAFrVq6z2ntiGzjEfcsh+J45ATfhJD6wQAWUh+QQp7HYf+FzDvPsSEuqXAGW2xaQ2uYpW9jNJrz+nfrdTo9SbWq9hLsIkiu7vzI9n+G8RwBFc=):

App.vue:

```html
<template>
<Comp @focus-parent-el="callback" />

<input ref="myInput" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Comp from './Comp.vue'

const myInput = ref(null)

const callback = () => myInput.value.focus()
</script>
```

Comp.vue:

```html
<template>
<button
  @click="btnClicked()"
  v-text="`Click to focus input`"
/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
  
const emits = defineEmits(['focusParentEl'])

const btnClicked = () => emits('focusParentEl')
</script>
```